# Unable to resolve error of gradle version when migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, build.gradle, androidx

When I tried to migrate my own project to AndroidX, the error message appeared on a error dialog:

```
The gradle plugin version in your project build.gradle file needs to be set to at least com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0 in order to migrate to AndroidX.
```

Then I googled this error on the Internet. A site was found that it said `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` has to be added to the build.gradle. Therefore, I added the line to the build.gradle like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

However, the same error happened. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your `build.grade` of Project level ( Not Module )

And change the version of the android `gradle plugin`:

```
buildscript {
    ...

    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1' // it should be more than 3.2.0
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the correct answer. The site is just so unclear that it never told me to change the Project level one... Still, thank you!

Comment: It is not the gradle version. It is the version of the android gradle plugin